# Confused about majorclust algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab, text, cluster-analysis

I would like to write my own code in matlab for "majorclust" algorithm. I have document pairs having their cosine similarity. When i search through the web, i encounter this web site.

http://muse-amuse.in/~baali/MajorClustPost.html

In the example(written in Python) in this web site, the clustering part is given as follow:

```
t = False
indices = np.arange(num_of_samples)
while not t:
  t = True
  for index in np.arange(num_of_samples):
    # aggregating edge weights 
    new_index = np.argmax(np.bincount(indices, 
    weights=cosine_distances[index]))
if indices[new_index] != indices[index]:
  indices[index] = indices[new_index]
  t = False
```

When i examine the sample, i am a bit confused. When we consider the for loop:

```
for index in np.arange(num_of_samples):
```

the first index will be "0". And maximum similarity is retrieved with "1". So the new_index must be 1 and the index "0" will be replaced by "1".

On the next iteration index will be "1" and its maximum weight will come from "0" which has the same index from the previous iteration. As a result, after this point loop must terminate.

This algorithm is based on the paper (given on page 4):

http://www.uni-weimar.de/medien/webis/publications/papers/stein_2002c.pdf

On the paper, it is stated that index must be chosen randomly. But in the example
i could not see any random choice.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would be good if you shuffle the indices and you can do the same using

```
from random import shuffle
shuffled_indices = np.arange(num_of_samples)
shuffle(shuffled_indices)
for index in shuffled_indices:
    # aggregating edge weights 
    new_index = np.argmax(np.bincount(indices,weights=cosine_distances[index]))
    if indices[new_index] != indices[index]:
        indices[index] = indices[new_index]
        t = False
```

Sorry for such a late reply.